# Python: removing duplicates from a list while preserving order using a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a as a list:

```
>>> a = big_list(30)
>>> a
[-14, -13, 10, 7, -10, 5, 3, 10, 8, -13, 14, -12, 6, 10, 8, 7, 4, -8, -10, -3, -6, 2, -6, 3, -3, 0, -13, -14, 2, -12]
```

and I need to remove duplicates from a while preserving order using a dictionary

so far I converted a into a dictionary using this code

```
def only_once(a):
    i = iter(a)
    print dict(zip(i,i))
```

the output was:

```
>>> only_once(a)
{2: -12, 3: 10, 4: -8, 6: 10, 8: 7, 10: 7, 14: -12, -14: -13, -13: -14, -10: -3, -6: 3, -3: 0}
```

there are duplicates and they're arranged in an odd order, any ideas on how to convert it back into a list while keeping order and removing duplicates?

Comment: Have a look at http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes and the `unique_everseen` recipe. If you're just removing duplicates - you don't need to put the actual items as key/value pairs as you're doing...

Comment: There is no need to artificially use a dictionary if the expected result is not a dictionary. A `set` is generally more appropriate for dealing with duplicates.

Answer (score 3):

Use an OrderedDict:

```
x = [-14, -13, 10, 7, -10, 5, 3, 10, 8, -13, 14, -12, 6, 10, 8, 7, 4, -8, -10, -3, -6, 2, -6, 3, -3, 0, -13, -14, 2, -12]
from collections import OrderedDict
d = OrderedDict.fromkeys(x)
x = list(d)
```

Order is preserved here, in so far as the first occurrence of every duplicate is still in the same position.

Comment: I'm not convinced the OP requires `iter`, and the usage of `iter(x)` twice in this code is pointless - it's always just `x`... Also, no need to use `.keys()` - just use `list(d)`

Comment: No need for the `zip`, simply use `OrderedDict.fromkeys`.  But if this is the answer, then this question is a duplicate of many of the questions linked on the right.

Answer (score 2):

```
d = {e: i for i, e in enumerate (a) }
a = [x for x, _ in sorted(d.items (), key = lambda x: x [1] ) ]
```

When an item appears multiple times in the original list, its last occurence is preserved.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries do not store order.  To do what you're trying to do using only pure dictionaries, you will need to also store the position in the list in the dictionary.

```
def only_once(a):
    d = dict((b,a) for (a,b) in enumerate(a))
    new = d.items()
    return [x[0] for x in sorted(new, key=lambda a: a[1])]
```

This will create a dictionary with the keys being the elements and the values being the position in the list, meaning the first occurrence of an element will be overwritten by a later occurrence (call `reversed()` to switch this behavior).  Then, the `(key,value)` pairs will be pulled out of the dictionary, sorted by position in list, and truncated to just the elements.

Comment: `only_once ([1,1,1,3,3,2,2])` yields `[0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 3, 4]`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not specifying *how* the dictionary needs to be used and there is no indication that the code needs to be efficient I guess there are loads of possible answers to this. e.g. using indices

```
first_index = {v: len(a) - 1 - i for i, v in enumerate(reversed(a))}
print [v for i, v  in enumerate(a) if i == first_index[v]]
```

(I'm assuming that you want to remove duplicates that appear later in the list, while retaining the first occurrence.)

Answer (score -1):

Create a set of the items you're keeping, and discard items you've already kept:

```
>>> a = [-14, -13, 10, 7, -10, 5, 3, 10, 8, -13, 14, -12, 6, 10, 8, 7, 4, -8, -10, -3, -6, 2, -6, 3, -3, 0, -13, -14, 2, -12]
>>> s = set()
>>> [ item for item in a if item not in s and s.add(item) == None]
[-14, -13, 10, 7, -10, 5, 3, 8, 14, -12, 6, 4, -8, -3, -6, 2, 0]
```

A dictionary can be used instead of the `set`, but it's very artificial:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> [ item for item in a if item not in d and d.update({item:None}) == None]
[-14, -13, 10, 7, -10, 5, 3, 8, 14, -12, 6, 4, -8, -3, -6, 2, 0]
```

Comment: This is unfortunately *extremely inefficient* (O(n^2)). It slices the list (O(n) per iteration) and does a linear search for the item (another O(n) per iteration).

Comment: Changed to a O(n) solution.

Comment: The question states the solution should use a dictionary.

Comment: There is no need to artificially use a dictionary if the expected result is not a dictionary. Plus the `set` could be changed in a dictionary.

Comment: @btoueg: while I agree that the need is artificial, given that the OP's last question was about how to do this using a `set`, I'm pretty sure we're simply working through the OP's assignment questions.

Comment: I understand that, and that's why I added a solution using a dictionary.